# Table TD wraps still when using whitespace: nowrap

Tags: html, css

Why is this still wrapping? Here's my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="nowrap">
        $<input type="text" name="test" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and CSS:

```
.nowrap {
   whitespace: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I thought `whitespace: nowrap` was the equivalent to the `TD` attribute `nowrap`...

Comment: it does not wrap for me - http://jsfiddle.net/QWPwG/, what browser are you testing this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `white-space: nowrap;` with a hyphen.